# SQL Syntax Error and Event failing to start

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I've been trying to write an event trigger to update a table whenever the column "AISTATUS" is changed to the value "TRIGGER REQUIRED". I was unable to get a trigger to reference two separate tables to pull the values across that I need, so I've opted to use an event instead. Only catch is that I am getting a Syntax error: 1064 at line 1, But I'm struggling to understand why there is an error or where it is.

```
DELIMITER //    
CREATE EVENT Retention_Date_Update
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
BEGIN;
IF (gdpr_file_cabinet.AISTATUS = 'TRIGGER REQUIRED')
THEN
IF (gdpr_file_cabinet.EMPLOYMENT_STATUS = 0)            
THEN
UPDATE gdpr_file_cabinet
SET REVIEW_EXPIRY_DATE = (RETENTION_START_DATE + INTERVAL adata.EDB_RETENTION_EMPLOYED MONTH)
AND AISTATUS = "TRIGGER COMPLETE"                       
WHERE documentName = adata.EDB_DOCUMENT_NAME;                                       
ELSE
UPDATE gdpr_file_cabinet
SET REVIEW_EXPIRY_DATE = (RETENTION_START_DATE + INTERVAL adata.EDB_RETENTION_UNEMPLOYED MONTH)
AND AISTATUS = "TRIGGER COMPLETE"
WHERE documentName = adata.EDB_DOCUMENT_NAME;
END IF;
END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

I have two databases, each containing a table I need to reference from.
Database 1 is "adata", and Table 1 is "gdpr_data".
Database 2 is "dwdata", and Table 2 is "gdpr_file_cabinet".

A second issue that could be related is  that the event will create, but then will not start when I run the code as above. Global event scheduler is turned on (SET @@global.event_scheduler = 1).

Questions I have about this: 
1 - Can anyone identify the Syntax error please, as I cannot see it.
2 - Why does the event "execute at" box remain null.
3 - Can I set Workbench to highlight errors like this, as it currently doesn't warn me unless I try running the script.

Comment: IF (gdpr_file_cabinet.AISTATUS = 'TRIGGER REQUIRED') THEN is syntactically incorrect you need to select and you aren't reading adata You should fix the code before attempting to create an event and do research mysql multi-table update.

Comment: `REATE EVENT`???

Comment: @Nick I've Edited that, I accidentally deleted it when removing tab space from the code. it should read `CREATE EVENT`

Comment: @P.Salmon I was writing the IF using http://www.easysolutionweb.com/mysql-tutorials/how-to-use-if-and-else-in-mysql as a guide. where do I need to select within that line? I'll go and read into multi-table updates and see if I can figure out where it's going wrong from there.

Comment: The second if statement seems irrelevant since I cannot see any difference in the update statements.And the update statement is invalid you comma separate if you are updating multiple columns not an AND statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be just 1 update statement since the second if seems to be irrelevant

```
UPDATE gdpr_file_cabinet g join adata a on a.EDB_DOCUMENT_NAME = g.documentname
            SET REVIEW_EXPIRY_DATE = (RETENTION_START_DATE + INTERVAL a.EDB_RETENTION_EMPLOYED MONTH)
                , AISTATUS = "TRIGGER COMPLETE"                       
            WHERE g.aistatus = 'TRIGGER REQUIRED';
```

I haven't tested this, if you run into problems please read the manual and if struggling please add table definitions and sample data to the question as text.